# Creating a second website tree inside a typo3 backend for test purpose?

Tags: web, typo3, backend, content-management-system

I have a typo3 backend with a page tree.

I want to future change the structure of that website. For that purpose i want to copy&paste the existing page tree and make changes there for testing purpose. And if everything works out, i want to replace the existing page tree with the new one.

How do i do that?

I did try to just copy the existing page. But the copy option doesnt show up.

Comment: How did you try to copy the page?

Comment: Right click on the top page on the page tree.

Comment: "top page" means the one with the earth-icon, not the one with the TYPO3-icon, right?

Comment: the one with the typo3 icon

Comment: Have a look at workspaces from TYPO3 core. You can do variants in a draft mode. https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-workspaces/main/en-us/